# How adjust scale of a table in a container on Html?

Tags: javascript, css, asp-classic, resize, scale

I have a problem to automatically adjust a table in a div if the user adds collones or lines in the matrix. Even if its size exceeds, I wish he still full in my "container div" by setting a smaller scale. Is it possible to resize only my table keeping the size of my container ? Always keeping my table in the center ?

Here is my css used:

[image]

**CSS**

```
.container{
    background-image: url(image/block_surveillance_content.gif);
    background-position: bottom right;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 320px;
    height:400px;

}

.matrice{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="block" class="container">
  <table id="dataArray" class="matrice">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
                <asp:Table runat="server" ID="matrixColumnLabel" ></asp:Table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="matrixLineLabel" style="position:relative;margin:6px"></asp:Table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tableMatrice" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" style="margin:6px"></asp:Table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post the HTML too.. (Plus i must say, it is **really** difficult to understand what you've written, no pun intended).

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I changed the description of my problem and added the html code